# Hosted URL shortener

Tags: url

We do encounter an issue with a JWT token length, which is used within a SSO system. One of our client is using outlook 2007 and there is a known bug regarding the length of a link provided inside an email.

To bypass this bug we thought about hosting our own URL shortener, so I'm coming here to have  advice  (as there is quite a lot of URL shortener vendor out there).

Our goal is to be able to send our the link through an email and then intercept this email extract the link inside and shorten this link then send the email to the final customer.

Comment: What is your SMTP server?

Comment: We are using either our own smtp (postfix) or the one that comes with office365.

Comment: It is probably simpler to get used to using an existing URL shortener than to install one, let alone add a filter to your email server.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice. The problem here is that this is a private system, shared with the client through an IPSEC tunnel, therefore we do not have access to the web, that is why I initially searched for a hosted service...

Comment: If you already have a web server, just search Google for something like `url shortener script`.

Comment: Oh thanks for the good tips ! I did not even had the idea for this kind of search ! Thanks Julie

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of this programs:

> ### [URL Shorteners](https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted#url-shorteners)

- [Link-shortener-bot](https://github.com/tommyku/link-shortener-front-end) - URL shortener using a Telegram Bot. ([Demo](http://t.me/GiveMeShortLinkBot)) `MIT` `Ruby`
- [Linkr](https://linkrapp.com) - Beautiful, fast URL shortening. ([Demo](https://demo.linkrapp.com), [Source Code](https://github.com/LINKIWI/linkr)) `MIT` `Python/Nodejs`
- [Lstu](https://github.com/ldidry/lstu) - *Let's SHorten That Url* - Lightweight URL shortener. `WTFPL` `Perl`
- [Nimbus](https://github.com/ethanal/nimbus) - URL shortener and file sharer with a drag-and-drop OS X menu bar client and web interface. `MIT` `Python`
- [Polr](https://project.polr.me/) - Modern, minimalist, modular, and lightweight URL shortener. ([Source Code](https://github.com/Cydrobolt/polr)) `GPL-2.0` `PHP`
- [reduc.io](https://github.com/ziyasal/reducio) - URL shortener service written in Scala, using Akka-Http and Redis. `MIT` `Scala`
- [shorturl](https://github.com/prologic/shorturl) - Simple URL shortener with very tiny URLs. ([Demo](https://url.mills.io)) `MIT` `Go`
- [shuri](https://github.com/pips-/shuri) - SHort URI - Lighweight URL shortener. `MIT` `PHP`
- [url-shortener](https://github.com/cagataycali/url-shortener) - Shitty url shortener, emoji and AI powered. `MIT` `Nodejs`
- [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) - YOURLS is a set of PHP scripts that will allow you to run Your Own URL Shortener. Features include password protection, URL customization, bookmarklets, statistics, API, plugins, jsonp. ([Source Code](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/)) `MIT` `PHP`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already been through this list :)